# Control pan and zoom animation duration in mapbox.js

Tags: mapping, gis, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm making an animated map showing a series of points using Mapbox.js. Ideally, I want to smoothly switch focus between points by combining zoom and pan like this [example](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/zoom/) created in d3.js. I wonder if there is anyway to control the pan & zoom animation speed (mainly to slow it down). In the code below, I've tried both setView() and panTo() functions and the transition is too fast. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated, thanks!

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = "#Token Here";
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
        .setView([34.01, -118.48], 5, { 
            pan: { animate: true }, 
            zoom: { animate: true } 
        });

map.setView([33.98, -118.42], 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/k1uzrrcw/2/).

You can use a function like:

```
function jumpTo(index){
    map.setView(positions[index], 4, {
        pan: {
            animate: true,
            duration: 2
        },
        zoom: {
            animate: true
        }
    });
}
```

And control it on `moveend` event.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. Sorry I'm getting back to this a little bit late. Btw, may I ask how did you create the fiddle example without exposing your Mapbox access token? Just wonder how I can do the same.

Comment: You're welcome. Somehow I find this map id `examples.map-i86nkdio`, and somehow it doesn't require a token.

Comment: this does not work for me. Did the API change? I'm getting either errors, saying that the lat/long is null or it just jumps to the new position and does not animate.